# Special character in querystring - Umbraco 7

Tags: umbraco7

I am running a Umbraco 7 site and when I try to send some special character through Querystring it throws me an error.

For example:
When I try to go like this "/?query==abcæøåac

it throws me the following error:

Server Error in '/' Application.
Invalid URI: The hostname could not be parsed.

What to do?

Comment: Those double == are probably the issue? Otherwise you will probably just need to URL encode the value(s).

Comment: double "==" is my typo error...